# write to ms excel from ms sql server 2005 using java and poi

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-poi

I have a database table with more than 200 records.
I have to write this data to ms excel using java and poi api.
I am able to write the data. But, all the data appears in a single page (not sheet).
I want to split every 70 rows into different pages (not sheets).
Along with headers and footers i need it.

setautopagebreaks(true) sets it to every 30 rows by default

e.g., after every 70 rows, there has to be a page break.

How do i do this?

Comment: Start by looking at the POI examples: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook
 What you want to do seems straight-forward. If you hit a specific issue, post a question with some sample code.

Comment: i don't want new sheet, i want to split data to pages. set page breaks

Comment: http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#setRowBreak(int)

Answer (score 2):

Check : `public void setRowBreak(int row)`

[Link](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#setRowBreak%28int%29)